# displaying data returned from firebase on screen react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I have data being returned from my firebase query, but I cannot figure out how to display on the screen. take a look at this code:

```
firestore.collection('profiledata').doc(userID).get().then(doc => console.log(doc.data()))}
         
        render(){
    return(
        <div className='profile'>
            <h1>User</h1>
            {
                this.state.profiledata && 
                    this.state.profiledata.map( profiledata => {
                        return(
                            <div>
                                <p>
                                    First Name
                                    Last Name 
                                    Company Name                        
                                    </p>
                            </div>
                            
                        )
                    })
            }
            </div>
    )
}
```

where it says first name, last name, company name, I need to output the details of the user that I am returning from the line `firestore.collection('profiledata').doc(userID).get().then(doc => console.log(doc.data()))}` in my console it is returning this exactly:

```
   {
    "lastname": "x",
    "firstname": "x",
    "companyname": "x"
}
```

how do I output this to screen? thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set the data in your state.

```
firestore.collection('profiledata').doc(userID).get().then(doc => this.setState({ profiledata: doc.data() }))}
```

and where you map the data you just output the values

```
return (
  <div>
    <p>First Name: ${profiledata.firstname}</p>
    <p>Last Name: ${profiledata.lastname}</p>
    <p>Company Name: ${profiledata.companyname}</p>
  </div>
)
```