# how to display firebase data on screen in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am making a call to my firestore like so:

```
firestore.collection('profiledata').doc(userID).get().then(doc => console.log(doc.data()))}
```

the data is being logged as it should be where I am saying `console.log` in the line above... It is returning data like so in my console:

```
{ "lastname": "xx", "firstname": "xxx", "companyname": "xxxx" }
```

what is the best way to output this data to my screen? I am quite new to react and am trying to learn! What I have so far is this:

```
    render(){
return(
    <div className='profile'>
        <h1>User</h1>
        {

                        <div>
                            <p>
                                First Name
                                Last Name 
                                Company Name                        
                                </p>
                        </div>
                        
                    )
                })
        }
        </div>
```

Obviously this won't work, and those names last name, first name and company name are all just fillers, but how do I output this data to the screen? Any ideas?

Comment: what is `this.state.profileData` ? Array of Objects that you retrieved from database or only a single object containing `{ "lastname": "xx", "firstname": "xxx", "companyname": "xxxx" }` ?

Comment: @ShreyasJadhav sorry took that out now, was old code

Comment: How is this different from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66956596/displaying-data-returned-from-firebase-on-screen-react)?

Comment: may i know which in which variable you are storing the data from firestore? So i can write the code for you.

Comment: @ShreyasJadhav what do you mean which variable? If I am correct, I think you are saying like: `lastname`, `firstname`, `companyname`

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen this one is without mapping of arrays. trying multiple solutions

Comment: i understand when you console log `doc.data()` you get `{firstname, lastname, companyname}` as an object, right?

Comment: yes! @ShreyasJadhav

Comment: so are you storing that data in your component? can you share the code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230765/discussion-between-gianluca-and-shreyas-jadhav).